# How to change NSScrollView default text and make it non-editable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

I made an xib with a couple textviews, but it shows up as a scrollview. I would ;ike to make one of them, called objectives, to have a default text in it ant make it non editable. Is this possible? I have the @property in the .h and the @synthesize in the .m. Sorry if it looks rushed. It is late. I also control + dragged the NSScrollView to files owner if it helps.

Comment: Do you have any code you've tried that we can build off of?

Comment: @Ding I made the `@property` in the .h, and I have the `@synthesize` in the .m. In the .m, under `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification` i tried [objectives setString:@"text"] to set the text, but it didn't work. I couldn't find a clear answer for making it non-editable though. Am I even doing it right?

Comment: `@synthesize` has not been necessary for years.

Comment: @Zaph  When I don't use `@synthesize`, I either have to do `self.objectives` or `_objectives`. When I use `@synthesize`, I can do `objectives`. Is there any way around it?

Comment: Yes and that is correct. The point is to use self.propertyName everywhere except init methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `objectives` is declared to be a property of type `NSTextView` and connected to the textview:

1. Setting the text:

   [self.objectives insertText:@"My Text"];
2. Making non-editable:

   [self.objectives setEditable:NO];